# Dúvida angular - ngrx

Tags: angularjs, angular

Olá
Estava lendo sobre NgRx e me deparei com isso:

```
<div>Current Count: {{ count$ | async }}</div>
```

O que esse "|" quer dizer?

Comment: Isto **|** é um `pipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto `|` se chama PIPE (https://angular.io/guide/pipes), ele basicamente pega o input e "transforma" na saída desejada, no seu você está usando o chamado **"AsyncPipe
 impuro"**, que basicamente é o pipe que aceita `Promise`s e `Observable`s, ou seja ele passa o valor retornado por um destes diretamente ao teu "elemento"

Você poderia até mesmo retornar um array via Promise ou Observable que ele iria pegar o valor e então sim "popular" no template, algo como:

```
*ngFor="let item of dados | async"
```

Em um Observable ele continua observando e entregando esses valores a medida que eles vão chegando, um exemplo da propria documentação:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-message',
  template: `
    <h2>Async Hero Message and AsyncPipe</h2>
    <p>Message: {{ message$ | async }}</p>
    <button (click)="resend()">Resend</button>`,
})
export class HeroAsyncMessageComponent {
  message$: Observable<string>;

  private messages = [
    'You are my hero!',
    'You are the best hero!',
    'Will you be my hero?'
  ];

  constructor() { this.resend(); }

  resend() {
    this.message$ = interval(500).pipe(
      map(i => this.messages[i]),
      take(this.messages.length)
    );
  }
}
```

Note que o meio segundo (500ms) é para você notar a troca entre cada item, basicamente ele vai exibindo um de cada vez por causa do `interval(500)`, seria interessante para um sistema de "status".

Para ficar mais fácil de entender criei um exemplo que você pode testar online:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-playground-15djzg?file=src/app/app.component.html